# Encoding a String in 2 Steps (to ISO-8859-1 then to UTF-8)

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I guess I figured this is more the question I'm looking for. I hope at least

i got this String declared within Java

```
input = "||3.2|2013-01-25T17:24:00|ingreso|PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION|6386.21|MXN|7408.00|No identificado|NAUCALPAN DE JUÁREZ, ESTADO DE MEXICO|CAOS640116HT5|OSCAR MARTIN CARRERA|CTO. ORADORES 33|33|CD. SATELITE|NAUCALPAN DE JUÁREZ|ESTADO DE MEXICO|MÉXICO|53100|CTO. ORADORES 33|33|CD. SATELITE|NAUCALPAN DE JUÁREZ|ESTADO DE MEXICO|MÉXICO|53100|Persona Física con Actividad Empresarial|BAÑ930616R66|BAÑOMOBIL, S.A. DE C.V.|Av. 1° de Mayo|197|San. Lorenzo|TLALNEPANTLA DE BAZ|ESTADO DE MEXICO|MÉXICO|54047|1|NO APLICA|Dominio .com|Dominio por 1 año www.sanitariosportatiles.com|586.21|586.21|1|NO APLICA|Hospedaje 2 Gb|Hospedaje 2 Gb por 1 año www.sanitariosportatiles.com|5800.00|5800.00|IVA|16.00|1021.79|1021.79||";
```

Is it possible to convert it to ISO-8859-1 and then to UTF-8? Is it pointless to convert it to ISO-8859-1 first?

Basically, all I need is to have that String in utf8 bytes and I don't know if because some characters come from ISO-8859-1 I have to convert it to that first, then to UTF-8 or what would be the proper procedure to achieve it.

Comment: String variables themselves do not contain an encoding. Encoding only becomes relevant when saving characters to byte representation.  You never need to worry about how the JVM itself handles them in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need two steps.

You can simply use:

```
byte[] utf8bytes = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
```